# How does Doctor Octopus know the Green Goblin’s identity?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In Spider-Man: No Way Home, Doc Ock and Spider-Man are fighting on a bridge when the Green Goblin attacks. Doc Ock then says “Osborn?" In a later scene, he then confirms that he knows that Osborn and the Goblin are the same person.

How would he know this? In the Raimi movies, it was covered up that Osborn was the Goblin, and even his own son doesn’t find out until after Octavius’ death.

Comment: It’s not like things were all that inconspicuous. A smart person who also knew Peter Parker and the Osbornes personally could likely piece together things.

Comment: because he is smart?

Answer (score 3):

Doc Ock, at least in the movies, was a good person with lofty ambitions, but due to an accident, he loses control over his mind, giving the AI-tentacles complete control over how he thinks and his actions. It is almost like living inside another master body.

Now, his intelligence is still good enough and he can join the dots to know that Norman Osborn and the Green Goblin are one and the same, thanks to the fight between the Goblin and Spider-Man in the first movie, and the subsequent death of Norman Osborn.

There is also the comic storyline that shows them to be friends initially, but later on become enemies/rivals, due to a conflict of interests between them.

Comment: Doc also says that Osborne was found stabbed by his own glider; an event as such must have made the news...

Comment: @Peter Nielsen - It was the Sandman who mentioned that Osborn was impaled by his own glider, and he also stated that Osborn's death was all over the news: _"They both died. Fighting Spider-Man. It was all over the news. Green Goblin? Impaled by the glider he flew around on. And a couple of years later… you. Doc Ock. Drowned in the river with your machine."_ The way he phrased it didn't strictly confirm that the manner of Osborn's death was reported in the news, but it's not obvious how else he would've learned of that.

Answer (score 0):

Both Norman and Doc Ock knew each other before their incidents. Obviously, both being scientists and friends, they would share with each other what they were working on. Doc knows that Norman designed the glider, and on the bridge in No Way Home, he recognized Norman's laugh and was able to put it together.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer by pointing to exactly where/how Doc Ock learns that Osborn designed the glider.

Comment: Also when it comes to Sandman knowing, this could also be explained. Obviously some time has passed since the third Spider-Man movie in that universe. Bernard [Harry's butler] probably revealed that Norman was Green Goblin to the public after the events of Spider-Man 3, and he didn't do so before, because, as he says in the film, he loved Harry as he loved his father. He told him when he did because things were getting worse and he could no longer hide that from Harry.

Comment: Also, the public was aware of his death, just not that he was Green Goblin, but with Bernard's new info, the Daily Bugle now has a news update and let's everyone know the new details that were kept hidden. Sandman was talking about a news report that happened after the ending of Spider-Man 3. That's how the public knew of Osborn. Now when it comes to him an the public knowing about Otto's death, that doesn't make sense considering in SM3 there's a newspaper that says something along the lines of "still at large." So I will give you Otto's death being public knowledge

Comment: @Dylan - The Sandman knew that Osborn was impaled by his own glider, and stated that his death was all over the news. This implies that Ock either should, or at least could have, learned that Osborn was the Green Goblin before encountering him on the bridge.

Comment: That's just an assumption, but I think it does make sense. After losing both Harry and Norman, Bernard probably couldn't live with holding this information. He withheld it from Harry and that lead to him becoming insane. Bernard loved both Norman and Harry. Seeing how much damage withholding this info did to Harry, he probably wouldn't want to keep it a secret anymore, that everyone has a right to know.

Comment: @Dylan - Why is it probable that Bernard would've revealed to the public that Norman was the Green Goblin after the events of _Spider-Man 3_? What would've motivated him to do that?

Comment: @Dylan - It wasn't not knowing that his father was the Green Goblin that caused Harry to go mad. He learned of that in _Spider-Man 2_. The only thing Bernard telling him about the nature of Norman's wounds changed is that Harry no longer blamed _Spider-Man_ for Norman's death. Both Norman and Harry's mental problems were ultimately rooted in the Goblin serum itself. As we saw in _No Way Home_, Norman's sanity was restored once the serum in his system was neutralised.

Comment: @Dylan - I don't see how any of this would motivated Bernard to tell the _public_ that Norman was the Green Goblin. Regardless of what happened to Harry, the public certainly weren't going mad due to the lack of that knowledge. It also seems rather disloyal to the Osborn family for Bernard to do that; he'd essentially have been blackening the Osborn name.

Comment: Maybe insane isn't the right word. What I meant was not knowing that Norman essentially killed himself led to him hunting Peter throughout SM3. Also Bernard withheld the info in the first place was because he thought Harry wouldn't accept that, but the state Harry was in after his face nearly getting blown up and MJ being captured meant to Bernard that withholding it was no longer a good option. Mistake on my part it wasn't not knowing his father was GG.

Comment: Also I believe that after the people saw the new goblin help Spider-Man in the final battle in SM3, people would want to know who helped Spidey. Bernard probably wanted people to remember Harry for his heroism in that moment. Then when people were curious about his father they would know all of the details from him, and they would see how Harry in the end, didn't let his father's misdeeds control him, he died as a hero, instead of living as a villain.

Comment: The easiest answer if you don't accept, and this one is my least favorite, it makes sense if you've seen "What If...?" In the show "What If...?" there are separate universe where things were either COMPLETLY different, EXACTLY the same, or [and this is important] SIMILAR YET DIFFERENT. Things played very similar in certain universes, but with slight changes to differentiate itself from the main MCU timeline. This could be the case here there's an alternate universe of the Raimi universe where things were VERY SIMILAR, but with minor changes like Otto's death being public knowledge.

Comment: But ultimately I think the other explanation is better, at least to me, as it doesn't involve answers involving other universes, and it would make sense within the confines of the old and new movies.

Comment: I'm not an expert, I'm just trying to make sense of it by using knowledge of characters and events from the movies. I have my issues with the film, it's not perfect, and there are some things that muddy the film. But I think that the positives outweigh almost all negatives. I would give the film and A-. It's such an emotional experience and Peter grows into who we all knew he would become. What are you're thoughts.